# Trying to understand how an isomorphic react app is supposed to do client-side routing

Tags: reactjs, client-side, isomorphic-javascript

Pardon my English, it is a second language. The whole point of an isomorphic app, as opposed to a regular client-side SPA is so the client doesn't have to download the whole JS file initially which results in really slow initial load time.

I've been trying to teach myself server-side rendered React, and after watching countless videos around the concept and following countless tutorials on the actual implementation, I still can't get my head around this (at least this is how I understand it):

Despite the server conditionally rendering pages and sending props to the client on url change, the client side still uses a router that includes all the entry points for the app (by requiring all of them, and then loading the file based on the url location). Doesn't that means all the files are included in the main client JS file anyways since it's already been required by the client-side router? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of server-rendered React? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

In short, how does an isomorphic React app really works with a client-side router that includes (by requiring them) all of the app's entry points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that "The whole point of an isomorphic app [...] is so the client doesn't have to download the whole JS file initially which results in really slow initial load time" is necessarily true. I think the primary reason people do this is for SEO reasons and to improve perceived load time. You still get the benefit of showing the users the page before they have to load all the JavaScript (e.g. yes, they have to load all the JS, but it's OK because they already have most/all of the content). The app upgrades to an SPA transparently, providing a seamless experience for the user.

That said, you can implement a system where you don't have to load all the JS at once with something like [webpack's code splitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html). There's even [a simple React Router example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/partial-app-loading) that does this.